# How can we bring an old question back to the users' attention?

Tags: support, questions

The question we want to ask might have been posted by another user years ago. It is possible that the question did not get any answers or the answers were/are not satisfactory.

What should we do for each case? How can we bring an old question back to the attention of the community, i.e. make it appear in the *active* page again?

Answer (score 7):

Any user with more than 75 reputation points can [“spend” some of that reputation on a bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).  Bountied questions are [featured](https://physics.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties) for up to a week, and new answers (or other activity) on bountied questions will put them on the front page like other active posts.